# AsyncSocket doesn't work for me

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, asyncsocket

I'll start by saying i did look and searched everywhere before asking here
I'm trying to write a simple app for iphone the simply connect to an IP and port via telnet,
I tried everything i'm new to  obj-c (in java it took me four min),
I don't want to use threads but i heard that asyncsoket is pretty good.. well i don't know why but when I try:

```
AsyncSocket * socket = [[AsyncSocket alloc] initwithDelegate:self];
```

```
[socket connectToHost:@"localhost" onPort:444 error:&err]
```

(which is a server that works)
its simply not connecting...

All I need is to connect to a socket write and read data...
Is there any simple code example (no threading, no runloop) that I can use as a base?

Comment: did u implement any of the delegate methods?

Comment: no... i didn't... do you know how can i run this from main by the way?

Comment: What do you mean by main? Are you creating a command line app? If so, you will have to use nsrunloop.

Answer (score 0):

ConnectDelegate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "AsyncSocket.h"

@class AsyncSocket;
@interface ConnectDelegate: NSObject {
    AsyncSocket *connectSocket;
}
- (void)connect;

@end
```

ConnectDelegate.m

```
#import "ConnectDelegate.h"
#import "AsyncSocket.h"

@implementation ConnectDelegate

- (id) init;
{
    if( ![super init] )
    return nil;
    return self;
}

- (void)connect
{
    connectSocket  = [[AsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    connectSocket.delegate = self;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![connectSocket connectToHost:@"192.168.1.103" onPort:4000 error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error starting client: %@", error);
        return;
    }
}

- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:(UInt16)port{
    NSLog(@"connected to server");
}
- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag{
    // some relevant code goes here
}
- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didWriteDataWithTag:(long)tag{
}
@end
```

main.m

```
int main(int const argc, char * const argv[] ) {
    ConnectDelegate *SocketConnection = [[ConnectDelegate alloc] init];
    [SocketConnection connect];

    // Run runloop
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];

return 0
}
```